# Select japanese character from sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite, character-encoding, cjk

I created a database from the [Edict](http://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/edict.html) files with java and i used for that SQLite.

SQLite by default encode the string in UTF-8

Here is a sample of the database: [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8KtB.png)

If i do

```
Select* FROM entry
```

In Java i get the japanese words in their "correct" form (graphical representation at least).

But if i try and do.

```
Select * FROM entry WHERE wordJP LIKE '食べる'"
```

I obviously get nothing. That makes it very hard to find the definition of a word.

Can someone explain why this is occuring, and how to solve it ? 
I kind of understand that it is a problem of encoding but i don't understand where it happens and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i managed to solve this:

- Using iconv from linux to encode the file from EUC-JP to UTF-8
- Setting SQLITE to UTF-8
- Java is supposed to be natively in UTF-8, but eclipse put it by default on some ISO-xxx codage, so you need to change that by right-clicking on your project > properties  > text file encoding > other (scroll the list)

Answer (score 0):

From your link,

> [EDICT] is a plain text document in EUC-JP coding.

If you query strings are encoded in UTF-8, matching will fail.

You should probably try to convert the database into UTF-8 when you fill-in your sqlite database.

Comment: I know that it is encoded in EUC-JP, but i don't understand how can i convert it to UTF-8